# Separating gold, platinum and palladium

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I've dissolved all 3 metals together in aqua regia due to them being mixed together as $\ce{Pt}$ black, $\ce{Pd}$ black and gold. I isolated the gold with no problem using sodium metabisulfate, but I am struggling to separate the $\ce{Pt}$ and $\ce{Pd}$. Any suggestions? I have tried sodium chlorate for palladium isolation and ammonium chloride for platinum isolation, none had worked for some reason. Any tips would be amazing.

Comment: Palladium and platinum are in Group 10, gold in Group 11.  This is not a solution but indicates why the gold was relatively easy to get out.

Comment: What is the point of this exercise? Sounds to me as if this should be done under the supervison of some trained chemist, as with using aqua regia etc.

Comment: https://www.google.com/patents/US3024084.

Comment: I am doing it as a side project in work due to PGM waste. I am the chemist for the lab.